# Disable Enhance monitoring in RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have Enabled enhance monitoring for RDS instance using cloudformation template.

Now When i am trying to disable  enhance monitoring its not working.

As per documentation i have set Monitoring Interval to 0 and same i have verified cloudformation latest parameters. But still enhance monitoring is not disabled.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html

Cloudformation is not throwing any error and its getting updated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It is better to think of this community like you do for Wikipedia. Users come here with a specific question in mind, looking for a specific answer. Therefore, we require a description of the problem, your own attempt at solving the problem, the errors you are getting and what the expected output is. If those boxes are ticked, some kind volunteer may help you out. Please refer to this for more information https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I hope you have a good time here!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CLI first to verify (and apply to your CloudFormation template afterwards).

To disable Enhanced Monitoring using the AWS CLI, set the `--monitoring-interval` option to `0` in the these commands.

**For Linux, macOS, or Unix:**

```
aws rds modify-db-instance \
    --db-instance-identifier mydbinstance \
    --monitoring-interval 30 \
    --monitoring-role-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/emaccess
```

**For Windows:**

```
aws rds modify-db-instance ^
    --db-instance-identifier mydbinstance ^
    --monitoring-interval 30 ^
    --monitoring-role-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/emaccess
```

For further info, you can take a look at [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Monitoring.OS.html#USER_Monitoring.OS.Enabling).